# C# keep selection of DataGrid when using MySqlDataAdapter as DataSource

Tags: c#

I am aiming to keep selection after data has been refreshed.

**This is my current code how I load data into Data Grid View.**

```
   public void RefreshGrid()
    {
        try
        { 
            // MySQL connection string
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
            {
                using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id, customer from table;", conn))
                {
                    using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                        labelOrderData.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                        labelOrderData.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
                        labelOrderData.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Customer";
    
                        labelOrderData.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
         

    }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Refresh - Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
         }
     }
```

**This is how I refresh.**

```
private void refreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshGrid();  
}
```

**Question**

How do I keep selection after I refresh data?

I have tried this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/149500/c-Datagrid-retain-Cell-focus-after-refresh

But this does not work for me. This is because there is a point where the DataGridView is empty and has no data, and an error is thrown because these two lines of code

```
 int cell1 = (this.agentsDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
 int cell2 = (this.agentsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
```

are not valid / not selected.

Comment: You are creating a new DataSet each time you do a query.  If you just create the DataSet once the adapter will append data to the existing DataSet.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use the actual data, rather than the index, to choose what row to select after the refresh, because rows could have been added or deleted or the order of the rows might not be assured. I suggest this:

```
public void RefreshGrid(int selectedID)
    {
        try
        {
            // MySQL connection string
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
            {
                using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id, customer from table;", conn))
                {
                    using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                        labelOrderData.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                        labelOrderData.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
                        labelOrderData.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Customer";

                        labelOrderData.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                foreach(DataGridViewRow row in labelOrderData.Rows)
                {
                    if((int)row.Cells[0].Value == selectedID)
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Refresh - Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Then in your refresh button click event:

```
private void refreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedID = -1;
    if (labelOrderData.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        selectedID = (int)labelOrderData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
    }
    RefreshGrid(selectedID);
}
```

That code assumes that your ID can never be less than zero and the ID's are unique integers. If  they are something else, like strings, then adjust as needed and it will still work.

Comment: On Form Load - calling `RefreshGrid()` will not work

Comment: @LV98... ? There is no Form_Load in the answer that I posted, so I am not sure what your point is....? But still, I don't see why it would not work if called from Form_Load. What do you mean it "will not work"?